# Jaxws doesn't populate results

Tags: java, jax-ws, jaxws-maven-plugin

I have a working web service made with Axis1, and I'm migrating it to Jaxws

I'm creating my client classes with wsimport and maven from my working WSDL file.

The problem I have is that I can see my SOAP response message with data in my logger, but the objects aren't populated with this data.

My **wsdl** looks like this (I posted only 1 service to make it shorter and removed some of the elements, so please ignore if there are some missing like ResultadoProcesamiento):

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.test" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
    xmlns:impl="http://ws.test" 
    xmlns:intf="http://ws.test" 
    xmlns:tns1="http://pojo.test" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsdl:types>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
       <import namespace="http://pojo.test"/>
       <element name="validarCertificado">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="cert" type="xsd:string"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
       <element name="validarCertificadoResponse">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="validarCertificadoReturn" type="tns1:MensajeSalida"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
      </schema>
      <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://pojo.test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <import namespace="http://ws.test"/>
       <complexType name="Respuesta">
        <sequence>
         <element name="excepcion" nillable="true" type="tns1:Excepcion"/>
         <element name="resultadoProcesamiento" nillable="true" type="tns1:ResultadoProcesamiento"/>
        </sequence>
       </complexType>
       <complexType name="MensajeSalida">
        <sequence>
         <element name="peticion" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
         <element name="respuesta" nillable="true" type="tns1:Respuesta"/>
         <element name="versionMsg" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </sequence>
       </complexType>
      </schema>
     </wsdl:types>

       <wsdl:message name="validarCertificadoRequest">
          <wsdl:part element="impl:validarCertificado" name="parameters"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="validarCertificadoResponse">
          <wsdl:part element="impl:validarCertificadoResponse" name="parameters"/>
       </wsdl:message>

       <wsdl:portType name="WsTest">
          <wsdl:operation name="validarCertificado">
             <wsdl:input message="impl:validarCertificadoRequest" name="validarCertificadoRequest"/>
             <wsdl:output message="impl:validarCertificadoResponse" name="validarCertificadoResponse"/>
          </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:portType>

       <wsdl:binding name="WsTestSoapBinding" type="impl:WsTest">
          <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
          <wsdl:operation name="validarCertificado">
             <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
             <wsdl:input name="validarCertificadoRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
             </wsdl:input>
             <wsdl:output name="validarCertificadoResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
             </wsdl:output>
          </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>

       <wsdl:service name="WsTestService">

       </wsdl:service>

    </wsdl:definitions>
```

I forced to create 2 packages because I had some elements with the same name but from different schemas.

First package:

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://ws.test", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package test.ws;
```

**ValidarCertificadoResponse.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "validarCertificadoReturn" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "validarCertificadoResponse")
public class ValidarCertificadoResponse {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected MensajeSalida validarCertificadoReturn;
```

Second package:

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://pojo.test", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package pojo.ws;
```

**MensajeSalida.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MensajeSalida", propOrder = { "peticion", "respuesta", "versionMsg" })
public class MensajeSalida {

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String peticion;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected Respuesta respuesta;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String versionMsg;
```

And my response SOAP message (it includes only some tags):

```
<soapenv:Body>
<validarCertificadoResponse xmlns="http://ws.test">
    <validarCertificadoReturn>
      <peticion>value1</peticion>
      <respuesta>
         datas
      <respuesta/>
      <resultadoProcesamiento>
         more datas
      </resultadoProcesamiento>
```

After executing the client generated by jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3 my ValidarCertificadoResponse has the next attributes:

```
ValidarCertificadoResponse.java
   validarCertificadoReturn
       peticion = null;
       respuesta = null;
       resultadoProcesamiento = null;
```

Do you find something wrong? I guess there are mistakes in the WSDL or maybe the plugin is not creating the headers properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.

If we check the response SOAP message, we can see that there is only named one schema (http://ws.test), so every other element that belongs to the second schema cannot be transformed because jaxws doesn't find a match.

I cannot modify the web service because it isn't mine, so I adapted my wsdl to have only 1 schema. I guess it isn't the cleanest solution but it works.

Here is an example of how to do it:

**BEFORE**:

```
<element name="validarCertificadoResponse">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="validarCertificadoReturn" type="tns1:MensajeSalida"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

**AFTER**:

```
<xsd:element name="validarCertificadoResponse">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="validarCertificadoReturn">
        <!-- This is the content of tns1:MensajeSalida -->
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="peticion" type="xsd:string"/>
           <!-- This is the content of tns1:Respuesta -->
           <xsd:element name="respuesta">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="excepcion" nillable="true">
                  <!-- This is the content of tns1:Excepcion -->
                  <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="codigoError" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="resultadoProcesamiento" nillable="true">
                  <!-- This is the content of tns1:ResultadoProcesamiento -->
                  <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="resultado" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="versionMsg" type="xsd:string"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```